# Images stacked above - jquery fade

Tags: jquery, html

So i've been trying to figure out a way on how to hover over an image and have it transition fade into another. I came across a solution which works perfectly all except for one thing.
All the images are stacked above eachother.

I learned it here [replace image with rollover fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421951/replace-image-with-rollover-fade)

How do i make them go in a line?> i want it to be in a horizontal line.
http://trulyamped.com/test/duck.html

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
float:left;
```

to your `div`

Comment: Really? what browser are you using? works fine in Safari (havent tried it in any other browsers)

<div style="float:left;width: 160px; height: 160px; background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg); "><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverimg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg" style="opacity: 1; "></div><div style="float:left;width: 160px; height: 160px; background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg); "><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverimg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg" style="opacity: 1; "></div>    
    Sorry about formating :S

Comment: @TeoAlmonte, add style here:   $this.wrap('<div style="float:left">')

Comment: thanks nevermind, it works but when i float on the site i actually want to use it on it gets buggy i think i need to find a way that does not involve floating look at bottom http://trulyamped.com/test/index.html